# Kendo Mobile ActionSheet with TypeScript event handlers

Tags: typescript, kendo-mobile

I want to use a Kendo ActionSheet within a TypeScript mobile application. I cant see how to get the data-action to link to a TypeScript function within a class or alternatively to call a view.

Comment: CAn you provide some more information or a code snippet of what you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Here is my sample HTML:-

```
     <ul data-role="actionsheet">
        <li class="km-actionsheet-title">Payroll Processing</li>
        <li><a data-action="payrollProc.approve">Approve</a></li>
        <li><a data-action="payrollProc.unapprove">Un-Approve</a></li>
        <li><a data-action="payrollProc.extract">Extract</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The data-actions in JavaScript simply map to functions (as per http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/actionsheet documentation), however in Typescript, one needs to do a little extra to link the Typescript functions to the ActionSheet. Here is the way I solved it:-

```
declare var payrollProc: any;

class PayrollProcessingPage {
    constructor() {
        // Link the PayrollProcActionSheet to functions with this class..
        payrollProc = {
            approve: function (e) {
                // code for this action
            },
            unapprove: function (e) {
                // code for this action
            },
            extract: function (e) {
                // code for this action
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others.